# Create database link, 1 to many. Sample data and desired results included

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb2.2

I am in need of guidance on creating database link for 1 to many relationship.

I have a *class* called **Orders**. The class unique/primary *key is **id***.

I have a second *class* called **Order_Details**. Order_Details contains **order_id** (relationship back **orders.id**)

Every type of create link command I have executed, returns an error specifying that link cannot be created because of multiple records.

Please see below for my sample data and desired results below.

My goal is to have a link called Detail, on Orders that contains all Order_Details for the order.id record

**Current Data**

[image]

**Desired Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

I was able to figure it out on my own.

A combination of `LINKLIST` and `INVERSE` did the trick.

Originally, I was executing `LINKSET` without `INVERSE`

syntax used:

`CREATE LINK Detail TYPE LINKLIST FROM Order_Details.order_id TO Orders.id INVERSE;`

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.